# When I try to compile project I get `Could not find resource 'findbugs-exclude.xml'`

Tags: maven, findbugs

When I try to compile project I am getting this error:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  13.981 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-05-01T14:48:00+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Could not find resource 'findbugs-exclude.xml'. -> [Help 1]
org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.ResourceNotFoundException: Could not find resource 'findbugs-exclude.xml'.
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.DefaultResourceManager.getResource (DefaultResourceManager.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.DefaultResourceManager.getResourceAsInputStream (DefaultResourceManager.java:67)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.ResourceManager$getResourceAsInputStream$1.call (Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall (CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call (AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call (AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.findbugs.FindBugsMojo.getResourceAsFile (FindBugsMojo.groovy:1331)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.findbugs.FindBugsMojo$getResourceAsFile.callCurrent (Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent (CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent (AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent (AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.findbugs.FindBugsMojo.getResourceFile (FindBugsMojo.groovy:1225)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke (CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke (MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod (ClosureMetaClass.java:384)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod (MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent (PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent (CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent (AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent (AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.findbugs.FindBugsMojo$_getFindbugsArgs_closure5.doCall (FindBugsMojo.groovy:889)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke (CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke (MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod (ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod (MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call (Closure.java:414)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call (Closure.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each (DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2040)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each (DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1895)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$160.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke (PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call (PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall (CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call (AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call (AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.findbugs.FindBugsMojo.getFindbugsArgs (FindBugsMojo.groovy:887)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke (PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent (PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent (CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent (AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent (AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.findbugs.FindBugsMojo.executeFindbugs (FindBugsMojo.groovy:1019)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke (PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent (PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent (CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent (AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent (AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.findbugs.FindBugsMojo.canGenerateReport (FindBugsMojo.groovy:549)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.findbugs.FindBugsMojo.execute (FindBugsMojo.groovy:688)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions (MojoExecutor.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ResourceNotFoundException
```

**java -version**

> openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
>   11.0.2+9-Debian-3) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.2+9-Debian-3, mixed mode, sharing)

**mvn -version**

> Maven home: /usr/share/maven Java version: 11.0.2, vendor: Oracle
>   Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 Default
>   locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8 OS name: "linux", version:
>   "4.19.0-kali3-amd64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

What can be reason?
Thanks.

Comment: See the output: ` Could not find resource 'findbugs-exclude.xml'.`...?

Comment: @khmarbaise should I define this file manually?

Comment: This file should be there... I don't know why this project can't be built...I would take a look into the version control system etc. .

Answer (score 0):

I had **FindBugs Maven Plugin** version **3.0.5**.
Just changed it on **3.0.4** and bug disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

try put your `findbugs-exclude.xml` file  under the project root directory(same level as pom.xml )